# How to add total from multiple column in SQLyog?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sum, sqlyog

```
SELECT DATE(DATE), 
       SUM(CASE WHEN pay_code = "AC" THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AS Cash,
       SUM(CASE WHEN pay_code = "BT" THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AS `Bank Transfer`,
       (Cash + `Bank Transfer`) AS Total 
FROM partial_payment
GROUP BY DATE(DATE);
```

When i run this query, i got this error :
Error Code: 1054
Unknown column 'Cash' in 'field list'

```
SELECT DATE(date), 
       SUM(CASE WHEN pay_code = "AC" THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AS Cash,
       SUM(CASE WHEN pay_code = "BT" THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AS `Bank Transfer`,
       ('Cash' + 'Bank Transfer') AS Total 
FROM partial_payment
GROUP BY DATE(date);
```

When i change it like the above, it run successfully but the total is not add up

[image: SQLyog]

Anyone know how to solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't reference columns created in the same select list. Instead you can use a *derived table* (a subquery):

```
SELECT Cash, `Bank Transfer`, (Cash + `Bank Transfer`) AS Total 
FROM (
    SELECT DATE(DATE), 
           SUM(CASE WHEN pay_code = "AC" THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AS Cash,
           SUM(CASE WHEN pay_code = "BT" THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AS `Bank Transfer`
    FROM partial_payment
    GROUP BY DATE(DATE)
) dt
```

Note: `('Cash' + 'Bank Transfer')` is trying to add string literals, and - as you have noticed - returns something completely different.

Comment: May i know what is dt ?

Comment: Just naming the subqeury dt. (Some dbms's require a name here, some don't.)

Comment: Error Code: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM partial_payment
    GROUP BY DATE(DATE)
) dt

Comment: I figure out already because got extra comma after `Bank Transfer`

Comment: Typical copy-and-paste accident...